# Is there a way to horizontally display a bootstrap cards in a razor foreach loop?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Im having a brain fart I want to display bootstrap cards using my for each loop in a horizontal manner. It is vertical by defualt.

here is my razor code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    var imgUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/images/profile/" + Html.DisplayFor(model => item.userName) + ".png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

            <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; text-align:center;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="@imgUrl" alt="Card image cap" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.displayName)</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <br />
            <br />

            }
```

here is the output [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzC02.jpg)

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line breaks, and add `display:inline-block;` to the style of the div with class "card".

Here is an example with 3 instances of the div:

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="Card image cap" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Name</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 20rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="Card image cap" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Name</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 20rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="Card image cap" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Name</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```